# Visual Studio 2017 does not find accurate Code Coverage

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage, xunit

we are working on Unit Test of a big project (more than 100000 LOC) using Xunit for the purpose of testing and we also need to find out Code Coverage  for that purpose we are using "Analysis Code Coverage" from the Visual Studio and we are very confused about the How Visual Studio find out the code coverage or on what basis?

**Problems:**

we have 72 controllers to be tested in which we tested 25 controllers

**Scenario 1**

1) when we test 1 controller Code Coverage result is **3.10%**  **That's fine**

that means we test every single controller 25 times (some of the controllers are taking 2%,2.15% etc.) result is **22%** **Great :)** compare to 
 **total code is 150000**

**Scenario 2**

1) when we test 25 controllers at single click Code Coverage result is just **11.25%**  **That's not fine :(**

even  **total code is 150000** compare to controller code

**What We Tried**

we have used **Customised Code Coverage Analysis Settings (.runsettings)** so that we exclude non-used dll or namespace but we even getting an unsatisfied numbers

help me out thank you